# Is there a free solution for keeping a ventrilo server up?

Tags: ventrilo

I'd like to set up a ventrilo server that I want to keep up at all times, but I don't want to have to keep my computer on all the time. Is there a free server or something that I can use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're running it in linux, you can use crontab to start a task as a specific user- log on as that user, then

First make sure you have the right permissions to start ventrillo - rather than using ./ventrillo_serv,  use sh /path/to/ventrillo/ventrilo_serv - if this works, you can add it to crontab, else you'd want to make the script executable

```
crontab -e
```

brings up a text file - this is your crontab

Add a line saying

> @reboot sh /path/to/ventrillo/ventrilo_serv

- this runs the command, at reboot (you can also use this to run commands every so often)

Presumably you could work out some way to start your server with [WOL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN) as well.

If its windows, you could probably throw a batchfile or shortcut into your startup menu

Answer (score 0):

I think the operating system you're using is important here.

I used to run a ventrilo server on a Linux machine for a long while. If you wanted to get real slick, you could write an init script (similar to the ones in /etc/init.d/) which will start up your Ventrilo daemon (take care to make sure it starts as a user other than "root").

However, a more accessible solution might be to create a script which checks if Ventrilo is running and starts it if it isn't. Then, you could stick that in a cron job and have it execute every 15 minutes or so.